# UPnP: GetPositionInfo через ~10 секунд

Tags: c, протоколы, upnp

Дорабатываю UPnP рендерер. При использовании в качестве клиента смартфона Nokia N82, клиент отправляет запросы `GetVolume` и `GetPositionInfo` примерно через 10 секунд после запроса `Play` и только после этого позволяет изменить громкость воспроизведения MP3 файла (то есть через это время посылает запрос `SetVolume`, хотя кнопка изменения громкости нажата раньше). Если отправлять значение громкости в `LastChange`, то клиент отправляет только запрос `GetPositionInfo` с тем же результатом. Как можно это исправить? Может быть нужно отправить что-то ещё или изменить какие-либо параметры?

Вот лог запросов:

```
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.058133 | webserver] Access /upnp/rendertransportSCPD.xml (text/xml) len=15697
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.145971 | webserver] Access /upnp/rendertransportSCPD.xml (text/xml) len=15697
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.172341 | webserver] Access /upnp/renderconnmgrSCPD.xml (text/xml) len=4783
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.197171 | webserver] Access /upnp/rendercontrolSCPD.xml (text/xml) len=13317
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.254485 | upnp] action 'GetProtocolInfo' for service 'urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ConnectionManager'
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.254520 | upnp] Action 'GetProtocolInfo'; Request: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:GetProtocolInfo xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1"></u:GetProtocolInfo>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.254891 | upnp] Action 'GetProtocolInfo' OK; Response <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:GetProtocolInfoResponse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1">
<Source></Source>
<Sink>http-get:*:application/octet-stream:*,...</Sink>
</u:GetProtocolInfoResponse>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.293082 | webserver] Access /upnp/renderconnmgrSCPD.xml (text/xml) len=4783
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.345439 | webserver] Access /upnp/rendercontrolSCPD.xml (text/xml) len=13317
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.469008 | upnp] action 'GetProtocolInfo' for service 'urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ConnectionManager'
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.469054 | upnp] Action 'GetProtocolInfo'; Request: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:GetProtocolInfo xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1"></u:GetProtocolInfo>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:50.469390 | upnp] Action 'GetProtocolInfo' OK; Response <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:GetProtocolInfoResponse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1">
<Source></Source>
<Sink>http-get:*:application/octet-stream:*,...</Sink>
</u:GetProtocolInfoResponse>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.043786 | upnp] Subscription request for urn:upnp-org:serviceId:AVTransport (uuid:GMediaRender-1_0-000-000-002)
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.043919 | upnp] Initial variable sync: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/AVT/">
<InstanceID val="0">
<TransportStatus val="OK"></TransportStatus>
<NextAVTransportURI val=""></NextAVTransportURI>
<NextAVTransportURIMetaData val=""></NextAVTransportURIMetaData>
<CurrentTrackMetaData val=""></CurrentTrackMetaData>
<RelativeCounterPosition val="2147483647"></RelativeCounterPosition>
<PlaybackStorageMedium val="UNKNOWN"></PlaybackStorageMedium>
<RelativeTimePosition val="0:00:00"></RelativeTimePosition>
<PossibleRecordStorageMedia val="NOT_IMPLEMENTED"></PossibleRecordStorageMedia>
<CurrentPlayMode val="NORMAL"></CurrentPlayMode>
<TransportPlaySpeed val="1"></TransportPlaySpeed>
<PossiblePlaybackStorageMedia val="NETWORK,UNKNOWN"></PossiblePlaybackStorageMedia>
<AbsoluteTimePosition val="NOT_IMPLEMENTED"></AbsoluteTimePosition>
<CurrentTrack val="0"></CurrentTrack>
<CurrentTrackURI val=""></CurrentTrackURI>
<CurrentTransportActions val="PLAY"></CurrentTransportActions>
<NumberOfTracks val="0"></NumberOfTracks>
<AVTransportURI val=""></AVTransportURI>
<AbsoluteCounterPosition val="2147483647"></AbsoluteCounterPosition>
<CurrentRecordQualityMode val="NOT_IMPLEMENTED"></CurrentRecordQualityMode>
<CurrentMediaDuration val=""></CurrentMediaDuration>
<AVTransportURIMetaData val=""></AVTransportURIMetaData>
<RecordStorageMedium val="NOT_IMPLEMENTED"></RecordStorageMedium>
<RecordMediumWriteStatus val="NOT_IMPLEMENTED"></RecordMediumWriteStatus>
<CurrentTrackDuration val="0:00:00"></CurrentTrackDuration>
<TransportState val="STOPPED"></TransportState>
<PossibleRecordQualityModes val="NOT_IMPLEMENTED"></PossibleRecordQualityModes>
</InstanceID>
</Event>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.046444 | upnp] Subscription request for urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl (uuid:GMediaRender-1_0-000-000-002)
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.046544 | upnp] Initial variable sync: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/">
<InstanceID val="0">
<GreenVideoGain val="0"></GreenVideoGain>
<BlueVideoBlackLevel val="0"></BlueVideoBlackLevel>
<VerticalKeystone val="0"></VerticalKeystone>
<GreenVideoBlackLevel val="0"></GreenVideoBlackLevel>
<Volume val="100" channel="Master"></Volume>
<Loudness val="0" channel="Master"></Loudness>
<RedVideoGain val="0"></RedVideoGain>
<ColorTemperature val="0"></ColorTemperature>
<Sharpness val="0"></Sharpness>
<RedVideoBlackLevel val="0"></RedVideoBlackLevel>
<BlueVideoGain val="0"></BlueVideoGain>
<Mute val="0" channel="Master"></Mute>
<HorizontalKeystone val="0"></HorizontalKeystone>
<VolumeDB val="0" channel="Master"></VolumeDB>
<PresetNameList val=""></PresetNameList>
<Contrast val="0"></Contrast>
<Brightness val="0"></Brightness>
</InstanceID>
</Event>

INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.168648 | upnp] action 'SetAVTransportURI' for service 'urn:upnp-org:serviceId:AVTransport'
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.168752 | upnp] Action 'SetAVTransportURI'; Request: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:SetAVTransportURI xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">
<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
<CurrentURI>http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3</CurrentURI>
<CurrentURIMetaData>&lt;DIDL-Lite xmlns=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/&quot; xmlns:dc=&quot;http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/&quot; xmlns:upnp=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/&quot;&gt;&lt;item id=&quot;1$6$14D$1$0&quot; parentID=&quot;1$6$14D$1&quot; restricted=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;dc:title&gt;DISKPREPT1&lt;/dc:title&gt;&lt;upnp:class&gt;object.item.audioItem.musicTrack&lt;/upnp:class&gt;&lt;upnp:artist&gt;Aphex Twin&lt;/upnp:artist&gt;&lt;dc:creator&gt;Aphex Twin&lt;/dc:creator&gt;&lt;upnp:album&gt;Computer Controlled Acoustic Instruments Pt2 - (EP)&lt;/upnp:album&gt;&lt;upnp:genre&gt;Electronic&lt;/upnp:genre&gt;&lt;dc:date&gt;2015-01-01&lt;/dc:date&gt;&lt;res protocolInfo=&quot;http-get:*:audio/mpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=MP3;DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000&quot; size=&quot;8439808&quot; duration=&quot;0:03:29.972&quot; &gt;http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3&lt;/res&gt;&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/DIDL-Lite&gt;</CurrentURIMetaData>
</u:SetAVTransportURI>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.168782 | transport] AVTransportURI: http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.168801 | transport] AVTransportURIMetaData: <DIDL-Lite xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/"><item id="1$6$14D$1$0" parentID="1$6$14D$1" restricted="1"><dc:title>DISKPREPT1</dc:title><upnp:class>object.item.audioItem.musicTrack</upnp:class><upnp:artist>Aphex Twin</upnp:artist><dc:creator>Aphex Twin</dc:creator><upnp:album>Computer Controlled Acoustic Instruments Pt2 - (EP)</upnp:album><upnp:genre>Electronic</upnp:genre><dc:date>2015-01-01</dc:date><res protocolInfo="http-get:*:audio/mpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=MP3;DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000" size="8439808" duration="0:03:29.972" >http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3</res></item></DIDL-Lite>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.168823 | transport] NumberOfTracks: 1
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.168852 | upnp] Action 'SetAVTransportURI' OK
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:54.168941 | transport] LastChange: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/AVT/">
<InstanceID val="0">
<AVTransportURI val="http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3"></AVTransportURI>
<AVTransportURIMetaData val="&lt;DIDL-Lite xmlns=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/&quot; xmlns:dc=&quot;http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/&quot; xmlns:upnp=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/&quot;&gt;&lt;item id=&quot;1$6$14D$1$0&quot; parentID=&quot;1$6$14D$1&quot; restricted=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;dc:title&gt;DISKPREPT1&lt;/dc:title&gt;&lt;upnp:class&gt;object.item.audioItem.musicTrack&lt;/upnp:class&gt;&lt;upnp:artist&gt;Aphex Twin&lt;/upnp:artist&gt;&lt;dc:creator&gt;Aphex Twin&lt;/dc:creator&gt;&lt;upnp:album&gt;Computer Controlled Acoustic Instruments Pt2 - (EP)&lt;/upnp:album&gt;&lt;upnp:genre&gt;Electronic&lt;/upnp:genre&gt;&lt;dc:date&gt;2015-01-01&lt;/dc:date&gt;&lt;res protocolInfo=&quot;http-get:*:audio/mpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=MP3;DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000&quot; size=&quot;8439808&quot; duration=&quot;0:03:29.972&quot; &gt;http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3&lt;/res&gt;&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/DIDL-Lite&gt;"></AVTransportURIMetaData>
<NumberOfTracks val="1"></NumberOfTracks>
</InstanceID>
</Event>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.299957 | upnp] action 'SetAVTransportURI' for service 'urn:upnp-org:serviceId:AVTransport'
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.300050 | upnp] Action 'SetAVTransportURI'; Request: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:SetAVTransportURI xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">
<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
<CurrentURI>http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3</CurrentURI>
<CurrentURIMetaData>&lt;DIDL-Lite xmlns=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/&quot; xmlns:dc=&quot;http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/&quot; xmlns:upnp=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/&quot;&gt;&lt;item id=&quot;1$6$14D$1$0&quot; parentID=&quot;1$6$14D$1&quot; restricted=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;dc:title&gt;DISKPREPT1&lt;/dc:title&gt;&lt;upnp:class&gt;object.item.audioItem.musicTrack&lt;/upnp:class&gt;&lt;upnp:artist&gt;Aphex Twin&lt;/upnp:artist&gt;&lt;dc:creator&gt;Aphex Twin&lt;/dc:creator&gt;&lt;upnp:album&gt;Computer Controlled Acoustic Instruments Pt2 - (EP)&lt;/upnp:album&gt;&lt;upnp:genre&gt;Electronic&lt;/upnp:genre&gt;&lt;dc:date&gt;2015-01-01&lt;/dc:date&gt;&lt;res protocolInfo=&quot;http-get:*:audio/mpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=MP3;DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000&quot; size=&quot;8439808&quot; duration=&quot;0:03:29.972&quot; &gt;http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3&lt;/res&gt;&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/DIDL-Lite&gt;</CurrentURIMetaData>
</u:SetAVTransportURI>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.300099 | upnp] Action 'SetAVTransportURI' OK
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.332875 | upnp] action 'Play' for service 'urn:upnp-org:serviceId:AVTransport'
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.332922 | upnp] Action 'Play'; Request: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:Play xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">
<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
<Speed>1</Speed>
</u:Play>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.398485 | transport] TransportState: PLAYING
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.398533 | transport] CurrentTransportActions: PAUSE,STOP,SEEK
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.398545 | transport] CurrentTrack: 1
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.398553 | transport] CurrentTrackMetaData: <DIDL-Lite xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/"><item id="1$6$14D$1$0" parentID="1$6$14D$1" restricted="1"><dc:title>DISKPREPT1</dc:title><upnp:class>object.item.audioItem.musicTrack</upnp:class><upnp:artist>Aphex Twin</upnp:artist><dc:creator>Aphex Twin</dc:creator><upnp:album>Computer Controlled Acoustic Instruments Pt2 - (EP)</upnp:album><upnp:genre>Electronic</upnp:genre><dc:date>2015-01-01</dc:date><res protocolInfo="http-get:*:audio/mpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=MP3;DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000" size="8439808" duration="0:03:29.972" >http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3</res></item></DIDL-Lite>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.398564 | transport] CurrentTrackURI: http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.398573 | upnp] Action 'Play' OK
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:56.398642 | transport] LastChange: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/AVT/">
<InstanceID val="0">
<TransportState val="PLAYING"></TransportState>
<CurrentTransportActions val="PAUSE,STOP,SEEK"></CurrentTransportActions>
<CurrentTrack val="1"></CurrentTrack>
<CurrentTrackMetaData val="&lt;DIDL-Lite xmlns=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/&quot; xmlns:dc=&quot;http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/&quot; xmlns:upnp=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/&quot;&gt;&lt;item id=&quot;1$6$14D$1$0&quot; parentID=&quot;1$6$14D$1&quot; restricted=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;dc:title&gt;DISKPREPT1&lt;/dc:title&gt;&lt;upnp:class&gt;object.item.audioItem.musicTrack&lt;/upnp:class&gt;&lt;upnp:artist&gt;Aphex Twin&lt;/upnp:artist&gt;&lt;dc:creator&gt;Aphex Twin&lt;/dc:creator&gt;&lt;upnp:album&gt;Computer Controlled Acoustic Instruments Pt2 - (EP)&lt;/upnp:album&gt;&lt;upnp:genre&gt;Electronic&lt;/upnp:genre&gt;&lt;dc:date&gt;2015-01-01&lt;/dc:date&gt;&lt;res protocolInfo=&quot;http-get:*:audio/mpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=MP3;DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000&quot; size=&quot;8439808&quot; duration=&quot;0:03:29.972&quot; &gt;http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3&lt;/res&gt;&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/DIDL-Lite&gt;"></CurrentTrackMetaData>
<CurrentTrackURI val="http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3"></CurrentTrackURI>
</InstanceID>
</Event>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:57.022089 | transport] CurrentTrackDuration: 0:03:29
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:57.022155 | transport] LastChange: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/AVT/">
<InstanceID val="0">
<CurrentTrackDuration val="0:03:29"></CurrentTrackDuration>
</InstanceID>
</Event>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:57.522391 | transport] RelativeTimePosition: 0:00:01
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:21:57.522457 | transport] LastChange: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/AVT/">
<InstanceID val="0">
<RelativeTimePosition val="0:00:01"></RelativeTimePosition>
</InstanceID>
</Event>
... ещё несколько таких обновлений
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:05.526569 | transport] RelativeTimePosition: 0:00:09
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:05.526638 | transport] LastChange: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/AVT/">
<InstanceID val="0">
<RelativeTimePosition val="0:00:09"></RelativeTimePosition>
</InstanceID>
</Event>

INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.503017 | upnp] action 'GetVolume' for service 'urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl'
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.503065 | upnp] Action 'GetVolume'; Request: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:GetVolume xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1">
<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
<Channel>Master</Channel>
</u:GetVolume>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.503078 | control] cmd_obtain_variable: CurrentVolume for instance 0
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.503118 | upnp] Action 'GetVolume' OK; Response <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:GetVolumeResponse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1">
<CurrentVolume>100</CurrentVolume>
</u:GetVolumeResponse>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.527085 | transport] RelativeTimePosition: 0:00:10
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.527152 | transport] LastChange: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/AVT/">
<InstanceID val="0">
<RelativeTimePosition val="0:00:10"></RelativeTimePosition>
</InstanceID>
</Event>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.558209 | upnp] action 'GetPositionInfo' for service 'urn:upnp-org:serviceId:AVTransport'
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.558247 | upnp] Action 'GetPositionInfo'; Request: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:GetPositionInfo xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">
<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
</u:GetPositionInfo>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.558372 | upnp] Action 'GetPositionInfo' OK; Response <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:GetPositionInfoResponse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">
<Track>1</Track>
<TrackDuration>0:03:29</TrackDuration>
<TrackMetaData>&lt;DIDL-Lite xmlns=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/&quot; xmlns:dc=&quot;http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/&quot; xmlns:upnp=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/&quot;&gt;&lt;item id=&quot;1$6$14D$1$0&quot; parentID=&quot;1$6$14D$1&quot; restricted=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;dc:title&gt;DISKPREPT1&lt;/dc:title&gt;&lt;upnp:class&gt;object.item.audioItem.musicTrack&lt;/upnp:class&gt;&lt;upnp:artist&gt;Aphex Twin&lt;/upnp:artist&gt;&lt;dc:creator&gt;Aphex Twin&lt;/dc:creator&gt;&lt;upnp:album&gt;Computer Controlled Acoustic Instruments Pt2 - (EP)&lt;/upnp:album&gt;&lt;upnp:genre&gt;Electronic&lt;/upnp:genre&gt;&lt;dc:date&gt;2015-01-01&lt;/dc:date&gt;&lt;res protocolInfo=&quot;http-get:*:audio/mpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=MP3;DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000&quot; size=&quot;8439808&quot; duration=&quot;0:03:29.972&quot; &gt;http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3&lt;/res&gt;&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/DIDL-Lite&gt;</TrackMetaData>
<TrackURI>http://192.168.1.136:8200/MediaItems/4442.mp3</TrackURI>
<RelTime>0:00:10</RelTime>
<AbsTime>NOT_IMPLEMENTED</AbsTime>
<RelCount>2147483647</RelCount>
<AbsCount>2147483647</AbsCount>
</u:GetPositionInfoResponse>


INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.619497 | upnp] action 'SetVolume' for service 'urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl'
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.619539 | upnp] Action 'SetVolume'; Request: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:SetVolume xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1">
<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
<Channel>Master</Channel>
<DesiredVolume>90</DesiredVolume>
</u:SetVolume>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.619567 | control] Volume: 90
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.619592 | control] VolumeDB: -1024
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.621074 | upnp] Action 'SetVolume' OK
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.621153 | control] LastChange: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/">
<InstanceID val="0">
<Volume val="90" channel="Master"></Volume>
<VolumeDB val="-1024" channel="Master"></VolumeDB>
</InstanceID>
</Event>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.653407 | upnp] action 'SetMute' for service 'urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl'
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.653447 | upnp] Action 'SetMute'; Request: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<u:SetMute xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1">
<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
<Channel>Master</Channel>
<DesiredMute>0</DesiredMute>
</u:SetMute>
INFO  [2016-07-25 16:22:06.653979 | upnp] Action 'SetMute' OK
```